# How to see all assigned color IDs in object mode

Tags: color

I've been adding Color ID mapping to many objects in my current model. What I can't find in Blender is a way to see all those color IDs at the same time in object mode. Even if I select all objects (in Object Mode) the only color ID mapping I see is the selected object. The reason I want to do this is so I can not only see parts that haven't been color ID'd yet but also to make sure I'm applying my colors coherently. My goal is to export the model into Substance Painter. thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you be more precise about what you call Color ID ?

Comment: To Gorgious... I call it Color ID mode but vertex paint is a better description, sorry about that. But I found my answer already, here it is. In Viewport Shading dropdown box there's an option called Color which has six options. I chose Vertex and that works perfectly. I found the answer here: https://blenderartists.org/t/seeing-vertex-paint-in-object-mode/1158358

Answer (score 0):

In Viewport Shading(Solid) -- Settings -- Color -- select Attribute parameter